# Boolean indexing array through array of boolean indexes without loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-indexing

I want to index an array with a boolean mask through multiple boolean arrays without a loop.

This is what I want to achieve but without a loop and only with numpy.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0, 1],[2, 3]])
b = np.array([[[1, 0], [1, 0]], [[0, 0], [1, 1]]], dtype=bool)

r = []
for x in b:
    print(a[x])
    r.extend(a[x])

# => array([0, 2])
# => array([2, 3])

print(r)
# => [0, 2, 2, 3]

# what I would like to do is something like this
r = some_fancy_indexing_magic_with_b_and_a
print(r)
# => [0, 2, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Simply broadcast `a` to `b'`s shape with [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) and then mask it with `b` -

```
In [15]: np.broadcast_to(a,b.shape)[b]
Out[15]: array([0, 2, 2, 3])
```

**Approach #2**

Another would be getting all the indices and *mod* those by the size of `a`, which would also be the size of each `2D` block in `b` and then indexing into flattened `a` -

```
a.ravel()[np.flatnonzero(b)%a.size]
```

**Approach #3**

On the same lines as App#2, but keeping the `2D` format and using non-zero indices along the last two axes of `b` -

```
_,r,c = np.nonzero(b)
out = a[r,c]
```

---

Timings on large arrays (given sample shapes scaled up by 100x) -

```
In [50]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: a = np.random.rand(200,200)
    ...: b = np.random.rand(200,200,200)>0.5

In [51]: %timeit np.broadcast_to(a,b.shape)[b]
45.5 ms ± 381 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [52]: %timeit a.ravel()[np.flatnonzero(b)%a.size]
94.6 ms ± 1.64 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [53]: %%timeit
    ...: _,r,c = np.nonzero(b)
    ...: out = a[r,c]
128 ms ± 1.46 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: In my code I had to do: `np.expand_dims(a, axis=-1)`. The shape of my a is now `(2, 3, 2)` and the b is `(2, 3)`.

Comment: @SparkMonkay So, as inputs - data array `a` is `3D` and boolean array/mask `b` is `2D`?